# Powershell-EXO - Error with RecipientFilter operator -contains when attempting to set new filters in Dynamic Distro list

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365, exchange-server

Connected to EXO via Powershell

Attempted script:

`Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity "Colorado" -RecipientFilter "(((((RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (CountryOrRegion -eq 'United States')) -and (StateOrProvince -eq 'Co')) -or (CustomAttribute3 -eq 'Colorado')) -and (-not(Department -eq 'Contractor')) -and (-not(Department -contains '-R')) -and (-not(Name -like 'SystemMailbox{*')) -and (-not(Name -like 'CAS_{*')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'MailboxPlan')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'DiscoveryMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'PublicFolderMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'ArbitrationMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'AuditLogMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'AuxAuditLogMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'SupervisoryReviewPolicyMailbox')))"`

Error: "Cannot bind parameter 'RecipientFilter' to the target. Exception setting "RecipientFilter": ""-contains" is not a valid operator."

the "-R" tag is how we are differing Remote employees vs onsite

Can I not use -contains in this manner?

Edit: For clarity:

If person A is in Dept: "Marketing", and person B is in Dept: "Marketing -R"

I want to exclude person B from the list.

I would use Custom Attributes instead but I have over 500 users and I'd have to do them 1 at a time :(

Comment: you can enter in code blocks using three (3) back ticks before, and after your code to make. I would ensure you're properly grouping the conditions, and ensuring that the properties you're filtering by are available to be filtered: [Filterable properties for the RecipientFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/recipientfilter-properties?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: Department is on the list provided, and the comparison operators found in: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2

seems to show I'm at least spelling it it correctly lol. 

If I take that specific operator and change it from "-contains" to "-eq" it works just fine, which leads me to believe the rest of the script is good.

Comment: without looking at each one individually, your very last property isn't filterable. `RecipientTypeDetailsValue` isn't listed in the link I posted above. I would recommend you read through them thoroughly.

Comment: ```Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity "ACI - Colorado" -RecipientFilter "(((((RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (CountryOrRegion -eq 'United States')) -and (StateOrProvince -eq 'Co')) -or (CustomAttribute3 -eq 'Colorado')) -and (-not(Department -eq 'Contractor')) -and (Department -notContains '-R'))"```
Cannot bind parameter 'RecipientFilter' to the target. Exception setting "RecipientFilter": ""-notContains" is not a
valid operator. For a list of supported operators see the command help.

Comment: `-NotContains` is to use against a list of items (*an array*). You would probably better off using `-NotLike`. So, it would be `Department -NotLike '*-R'`.

Comment: ```-and (-not(Department -like '-R'))``` was accepted. Now to test. Thank you for your help, sorry for the poor comms from my end